# how to use notifications in background in a thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, background, notifications

i ma making an app that will send files to client(another android device) while running in the background  and i want to show notification to server that the files has been sent from the background.and the files that server is sending are in an thread.

```
for (int i = 0; i < receivingTheFullPathOfFilesAndSendFilesToClient
                .size(); i++) {
            File f = new File(
                    receivingTheFullPathOfFilesAndSendFilesToClient.get(i));
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                    receivingTheFullPathOfFilesAndSendFilesToClient.get(i));
            long size = f.length();
            Log.e("size Of FIle is :", "" + size);
            sendData.writeObject(size);

            while ((len = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                sendData.write(buf, 0, len);

            }
            sendData.flush();
            // sendData.reset();
            fis.close();
        }
```

and after that for loop i want to hava notification that the files are send.i have watched the notification tutorials nad i have implemented that tutorials.but the problem is that i done want to open an activity like

```
public class StatusBar extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
NotificationManager mn;
static final int uniqueId=1394885;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statusbar);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstatusbar);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    mn = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mn.cancel(uniqueId);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // if ypu want tp open another class change status bar in tutorial 189
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SimpleBrowser.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body="this is a meagae from travis,thanx for ur support";
    String title="travis.c";
    //need to craate a notification i.e what the time is 
    Notification n=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,body,System.currentTimeMillis() );
    // add what details we want to our notification
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
    n.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;    
    mn.notify(uniqueId,n);
    finish();

}
```

}
when i use this setContentView(R.layout.statusbar) it open a content view and if i comment it i opens a simple blank activity. and i want that after sending files a simple notification comes that the file has been sent and without opening an activity

Comment: How about a simple Toast message instead?

Comment: as the server will run in the background and i want to show the list of files that are copied by client.

Comment: So you want 1) send files from server to client 2) for each file sent somehow notify the server device 3) be able to show a list of the files sent to the client ? I think if I get a full understanding of what you are trying to accomplish I might be able to answer